# how to cycle through table to pick up element values

Tags: jquery

I have this html table:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Map</th>
    <th>Source Table</th>
    <th>Target Table</th>
  </tr>

  <tr class="schema">
    <td>
      <input class="map" id="empire" name="source" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>empire</td>
    <td>
      <input class="hive" id="empire-hive" name="hive" placeholder="empire" disabled/>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr class="schema">
    <td>
      <input class="map" id="starfleet" name="source" type="checkbox" />
    </td>
    <td>starfleet</td>
    <td>
      <input class="hive" id="starfleet-hive" name="hive" placeholder="starfleet" disabled/>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

as you can see there's two rows involved.  There could be as many as 100s.  I have a button on the page, that when clicked, I need to perform the following:

1. go through each row and see if the checkbox is clicked in the first cell
2. if checkbox is checked, get values of second cell, and input in third cell.
3. if checked, take those values and send to ajax

I got 1 and 3.  What I don't have is 2.
How do I traverse the rows in jquery so I can perform #3?

Thanks.

UPDATE #1 first attempt:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  $('.schema').each(function() {
    if ($(this + " td input").attr("checked")) {
      source = $(this + " td:2").html();
      hive = $(this + " td:3 input").val();
      alert(source + " " + hive);
    }
  });
});
```

second attempt:

```
$('#save').click(function() {
  $('.schema').each(function() {
    if ($(this + " td:nth-child(1) input").attr("checked")) {
      source = $(this + " td:nth-child(2)").html();
      hive = $(this + " td:nth-child(3) input").val();
      alert(source + " " + hive);
    }
  });
});
```

I am still getting "targeting" issues with it.  Thanks much.

Comment: what you tried so far??

Comment: sister stuff. I'll post above:

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping through every row. just find the checked checkboxes then loop through those and step through the table cells getting the value and updating the textboxes. Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fsd2urgo/

```
$(function(){
  $('#save').click(function() {
    $('.map:checked').each(function(){
      var src = $(this).parent().next()
      var srcText = src.html();
      src.next().find('input').val(srcText);
    });
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .prop instead of .attr, like below. Also you had a incorrect use of $(this) and you have to use :eq() instead of :nth-child

```
if ($(this).find("td:eq(0) input").prop("checked")) { ...
```

Compare .find() : http://api.jquery.com/find/ and :eq() : http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/

Comment: This won't work if you try it. In this instance "this" is an object not a string. So $(this + " any text") throws an error. You can't concatenate an object and a string.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't check the rest of the given code. Now I corrected this in my answer.